# OpenJDK JRE textboxes become read-only after window loses focus

Tags: java, openjdk, knoppix

I have had this glitch happen in the DrJava IDE and in the Arduino IDE.  I can edit code and stuff just fine until I switch to another window and back.  All I can do at that point is position the cursor, nothing else.  The only solution I have found is to restart the program.  I am running KNOPPIX 7 with OpenJDK 7, and I am getting really annoyed.  It also happened with OpenJDK 6, so it's not a version compatibility thing or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer.

OpenJDK is a little stupid about stuff.  I downloaded the Sun JRE and JDK and it worked.

Hope this helps someone!